# pkexec "no such file or directory found" when trying to execute a binary from a script

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to execute a binary from a python script by using `asyncio`. I'm using the run command from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html). I tried running it regularly, but I apparently don't have the permissions (even though it did work with another binary) so I do know that the file name is correct. I also saw that pkexec might need the full path so I gave it the full path just in case and I still got the same error: `cannot run program ./linkerd: No such file or directory`

```
import os
import asyncio

linkerd_f = linkerd_name() # The file's name in the directory
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chmod(linkerd_f, 755)
asyncio.run(run(
    'pkexec .' + cwd + '/' + linkerd_f))
```

As for how I run the script, I simply run it through python:
`python3.7 script.py`

Comment: So in that example they define an async method `run()` that they then run using `asyncio.run()`. You have no such method, apologies if you simply omitted it for brevity.

Comment: I did omit it. The method is written out in the link. I copy-pasted it from there (it's the very first code block from the top) and I didn't think I needed to add it in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is being generated by pkexec itself as your call syntax is incorrect.

You used `os.cwd()` to get the CWD but then you prepend it with a `.` which invalidates the full path.

Effectively the equivalent of this:

```
amos:/tmp$ ll simple.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 amos amos 73 Mar 16 11:51 simple.sh*
amos:/tmp$ pkexec .$PWD/simple.sh
Cannot run program ./tmp/simple.sh: No such file or directory
```